# How to replace/inject html tags in a text in node?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I have a component in react js project which displays some text. the text variable is of type string and has some tab escape charcters within. I would like to replace this tab character and use a div . how do i replace this with a 
such that when it renders , it outputs the div within the  when it renders HTML. so on the page source in browser i see something like this => `<span> once upon a time, <div> there was a man <div> who had a house. </span>`

text = "once upon a time,  \t  there was a man \t who had a house." ;

```
class somcomponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <span> {text}</span>;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say tab, you refer to div with 'more text' as text?

Comment: @JoseRojas - in the string text there are these escaped tab characters "\t", which i would like to replace with actual html div ( <div>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your `text` by `\t` and render a `div` each split, like this:

```
class somcomponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <span>
      {text.split('\t').map(s=><div>{s}</div>)}
    </span>
  }
}
```

In a snippet:

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <Demo />,
  rootElement
);


function Demo() {

  let text = "once upon a time, \t there was a man \t who had a house." ;
  
  return (
    <span>
      {text.split('\t').map(s=><div>{s}</div>)}
    </span>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

`text.split('\t')` will split your text into a list of strings that are between '\t'.

Now, use `map` to render `<div>{s}</div>` for each element in that list, while `s` is current string you're iterating.

Comment: thank you very much. this works. one small problem i ran into was , in some examples , i had multiple tab escape characters instead of just one like this "\t\t\t " , wonder if there is a way to replace this with just  one div

Comment: Multiple tabspaces will result some empty strings elements in the list. So, you can filter out strings that are not empty before mapping. Like this: text.split('\t').filter(s=>s!=='').map(s=><div>{s}</div>)

Comment: thank you very much. I apologize in advance for this, but i am stuck here . looks like text.split('\t').map(s=><div>{s}</div>) this returns a array , not a string right? how can i convert this , if possible to a string so that i can assign it to a string type. i'm using typescript here so it is not letting me assign it.

Comment: Umm.. you can use `join` in some sort of way. But I am not sure why do you need that string (It will not render as divs, the way to render elements to DOM in ReactJS is rendering ReactElements). If you're sure it is necessary I'll try to try to give you that as well :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hi Ozil,**

Go ahead and give this snippet a try to see if this is what you are trying to achieve, pal! let us know the outcome on your end!

```js
const domEl = document.getElementById("container");
ReactDOM.render(<RemoveTabs />,domEl);

function RemoveTabs() {
let text ="Once upon a time, \t there was a man \t who had a house.";
return(<div>{"<div>"+text.replace(/\t/g,'</div><div>')+"<div>"}</div>);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. I am new to js , so this is just regular expression matching right?I know regular expression is a thing of its own and javascript has implemented it as well?

Comment: No worries, we are here to help, and yes, this is a regular expression(RegEx) that not only work on its own but that you can also integrate to most languages including the modern ones to help up in the process of solving issues by using patterns combined with some RegEx characters and with the help of this module's methods such as exec, test, match, matchAll, replace, replaceAll, search, split etc, that really expedite the string manipulation & validation process in most cases, please have a look at this link shorturl.at/fCUY9 to get started with the magical world of RegEx. Cheers, folk!